# When placing markers on map activity the camera move to the marker

Tags: android

I am using nearbyPlaces web service and I have a problem, I am putting a marker on the map for each pharmacie that it finds, but the camera always move to the marker and it does not stay in the current user position dot.

this is the code

```
public class GetNearbyPlacesData extends AsyncTask<Object, String, String> {

String googlePlacesData;
GoogleMap mMap;
String url;

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {
    try {
        Log.d("GetNearbyPlacesData", "doInBackground entered");
        mMap = (GoogleMap) params[0];
        url = (String) params[1];
        DownloadUrl downloadUrl = new DownloadUrl();
        googlePlacesData = downloadUrl.readUrl(url);
        Log.d("GooglePlacesReadTask", "doInBackground Exit");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("GooglePlacesReadTask", e.toString());
    }
    return googlePlacesData;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    Log.d("GooglePlacesReadTask", "onPostExecute Entered");
    List<HashMap<String, String>> nearbyPlacesList = null;
    DataParser dataParser = new DataParser();
    nearbyPlacesList =  dataParser.parse(result);
    ShowNearbyPlaces(nearbyPlacesList);
    Log.d("GooglePlacesReadTask", "onPostExecute Exit");
}

private void ShowNearbyPlaces(List<HashMap<String, String>> nearbyPlacesList) {
    for (int i = 0; i < nearbyPlacesList.size(); i++) {
        Log.d("onPostExecute","Entered into showing locations");
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
        HashMap<String, String> googlePlace = nearbyPlacesList.get(i);
        double lat = Double.parseDouble(googlePlace.get("lat"));
        double lng = Double.parseDouble(googlePlace.get("lng"));
        String placeName = googlePlace.get("place_name");
        String vicinity = googlePlace.get("vicinity");
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.title(placeName + " : " + vicinity);
        mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        //markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
        //move map camera
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14.0f));
    }
}
}

public class NearbyPharmaciesFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener {
private GoogleMap mMap;
double latitude;
double longitude;
private int PROXIMITY_RADIUS = 1000;
LocationManager locationManager;
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
AlertDialog alert = null;
Location mLastLocation;
Marker mCurrLocationMarker;
LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_nearby_pharmacies, container, false);
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if ( !locationManager.isProviderEnabled( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER ) ) {
        AlertNoGps();
    }
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        checkLocationPermission();
    }

    //Check if Google Play Services Available or not
    if (!CheckGooglePlayServices()) {
        Log.d("onCreate", "Finishing test case since Google Play Services are not available");
        //finish();
    }
    else {
        Log.d("onCreate","Google Play Services available.");
    }

    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    //SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    return rootView;
}
private boolean CheckGooglePlayServices() {
    GoogleApiAvailability googleAPI = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    int result = googleAPI.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getActivity());
    if(result != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if(googleAPI.isUserResolvableError(result)) {
            googleAPI.getErrorDialog(getActivity(), result,
                    0).show();
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}



/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

    //Initialize Google Play Services
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
    }
    else {
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }


}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }
}

private String getUrl(double latitude, double longitude, String nearbyPlace) {

    StringBuilder googlePlacesUrl = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
    googlePlacesUrl.append("location=" + latitude + "," + longitude);
    googlePlacesUrl.append("&radius=" + PROXIMITY_RADIUS);
    googlePlacesUrl.append("&type=" + nearbyPlace);
    googlePlacesUrl.append("&sensor=true");
    googlePlacesUrl.append("&key=" + "API_KEY");
    Log.d("getUrl", googlePlacesUrl.toString());
    return (googlePlacesUrl.toString());
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Log.d("onLocationChanged", "entered");

    mLastLocation = location;
    if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
        mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
    }

    //Place current location marker
    latitude = location.getLatitude();
    longitude = location.getLongitude();
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(latLng);
    markerOptions.title("Current Position");
    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
    mCurrLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

    //move map camera
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    float zoom=11.0f;
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(zoom));
    //Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Your Current Location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    mMap.clear();
    String pharmacy = "pharmacy";
    String url = getUrl(latitude, longitude, pharmacy);
    Object[] DataTransfer = new Object[2];
    DataTransfer[0] = mMap;
    DataTransfer[1] = url;
    if (new InternetWatcher().isConnectedToNetwork(getActivity())){
        GetNearbyPlacesData getNearbyPlacesData = new GetNearbyPlacesData();
        getNearbyPlacesData.execute(DataTransfer);
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.internet_para_ver_farmacias, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        getActivity().onBackPressed();
    }





    //stop location updates
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        Log.d("onLocationChanged", "Removing Location Updates");
    }
    Log.d("onLocationChanged", "Exit");

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;
public boolean checkLocationPermission(){
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Asking user if explanation is needed
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(),
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

            // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
            // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
            // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

            //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);


        } else {
            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {


    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // permission was granted. Do the
                // contacts-related task you need to do.
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                        buildGoogleApiClient();
                    }
                    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                }

            } else {

                // Permission denied, Disable the functionality that depends on this permission.
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return;
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other permissions this app might request.
        // You can add here other case statements according to your requirement.
    }
}

private void AlertNoGps() {
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setMessage(R.string.gps_no_activado_dialogo)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.si_gps, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(@SuppressWarnings("unused") final DialogInterface dialog, @SuppressWarnings("unused") final int id) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, @SuppressWarnings("unused") final int id) {
                    getActivity().onBackPressed();
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.gps_Required, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
    alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

Any help please? thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Your posted code includes these lines:

```
    //move map camera
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14.0f));
```

Sounds like you don't want to move the camera, so you should probably delete them.

Comment: I have done but the camera still does not center over the current user position after adding all the pharmacy markers